# Trouble install.packages("Hmisc")

Tags: r, install.packages

So I'm trying to download Hmisc to run a correlation matrix for my dissertation work, and for some reason it won't let me install the package, throwing me this error:

```
install.packages('Hmisc')
```

> Warning in install.packages :
>         unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
>         cannot open destfile 'C:\Users\Mia\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpEbYytB\file39745b63634', reason 'No such file or directory'
>       Warning in install.packages :
>         unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib:
>         cannot open destfile 'C:\Users\Mia\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpEbYytB\file39741a4d5c8f', reason 'No such file or directory'
>       Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection

Anyone have any idea how to make it work?

Comment: Do you have access to the temp folder where the package gets downloaded? I know that the stats.ox.ac repo is down. If you dont have access, download the package and use `install.packages("/path/to/package", repos = NULL)`

Comment: I can't replicate your issue on my computer; I was able to download from https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib. Can you post your session info?

Comment: By running that code I got another error

>Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Mia/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Error in gzfile(file, mode) : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile(file, mode) :
  cannot open compressed file 'C:\Users\Mia\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpEbYytB/libloc_191_882177c1.rds', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in install.packages : Error in gzfile(file, mode) : cannot open the connection

Comment: I think there's some connection issue, because seems to have similar errors with whatever package I try to install right now :/